# Is this a typo in official documentation?

Tags: javascript

I've read at the official documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators that:

> Null and Undefined Types are strictly equal to themselves and
>   abstractly equal to each other.

But I've checked it in browsers' console. So:

```
undefined == null --> true
```

but

```
undefined === null --> false //WTF?
```

So is this a typo in the documentation???

Comment: `==` is abstract equality.  `===` is strict equality.  So there's no typo.  `null===null`, '`undefined===undefined` ("strictly equal to themselves"), and `undefined==null` ("abstractly equal to each other")

Comment: The only "official" documentation would be the [ECMA-262 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm). the Mozilla site only contain a reference which may (or may not) follow the specification more or less closely, but the reference is a reference and not "official" in any way.

Comment: You should have first looked into what could `===` have meant before posting a question about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's ***strictly*** equal to themselves (see the docs for the difference between [strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) (===) and [abstract/non-strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_()) (==) equality) so it's

```
undefined === undefined // strict equal -> true
```

and

```
null === null // strict equal -> true
```

and

```
null == undefined // abstract equal -> true
```

but not

```
undefined === null // strict equal -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a typo, the documentation reads like this

> Null and Undefined Types are strictly equal to *themselves*

meaning that

```
null === null equals true
undefined === undefined equals true
```

and

```
null == undefined equals true
```

and conversely

```
null === undefined equals false
```

Answer (score 0):

`===` also fails if the given *type* is different, since it checks for **value** as well as **type** instead of just the **value** which is what `==` does e.g.

`'1' == 1 // => true`

BUT

`'1' === 1 // => false`

the difference can be seen using the `typeof` operator in JS

`typeof null // => object`

`typeof undefined // => undefined`

This is also the reason you'll want to always use `===` over `==` due to the number of crazy bugs out there being caused by type coercion.

If you don't know what type coercion is it simply means converting a type so that it can potentially match another type,

In this expression the number 1 will be converted to a string to match the string 1 using `==`

`if ('1' == 1)`

It is almost always best to leave the `==` as is and only use `===`.

so when `===` meets this comparison it automatically fails anyway.

Comment: It's what `===` is by definition, and not only in JS.